# Reference form component from datatable outside <h:form>

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, xhtml

I'd like to refer to the component id=contractIdInputText in the form below from a datatable  tag in a commandlink. I want to use its' id in the render attribute instead of @all. I used @all below only because i was not able to refer to the id. The datatable is outside and above the  tags.

```
<h:form id="contracts">
   <h:outputScript library="js" name="common.js" target="head"/>
   <h:panelGrid columns="3"   columnClasses="rightalign,leftalign,leftalign">

   <h:outputLabel for="contractIdInputText" rendered="true" value="Contract Nooo.: " />
   <h:inputText id="contractIdInputText" required="true"                                         value="#contractManager.newContractId}" />
</form>
```

This is the datatable's commandlink:

```
 <h:commandLink id="editLink" value="#{bundle.ListUnitEditLink}" 
     action="#{contractManager.updateContract}">
     <f:ajax onevent="disablePK" render="@all" />
 </h:commandLink>
```

The whole purpose of the ajax in the link is to disable the form component when i click the commandlink and populate the form. I've also noticed that much as using the @all does what i want (populate the form with the inputText disabled), it results in me needing to click the commandlink twice on an commandlink in he datatable for the form to be populated with another item. why is this happening?

Comment: I put the whole datatable in a <h:form> tag and removed the <h: form> tags that were enclosing the commandlinks. This solved the clicking twice issue on the commandink.

Answer (score 1):

If they are not in the same [`NamingContainer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/NamingContainer.html) parent, then you should just reference the other component by its **absolute** client ID instead of a (invalid) relative client ID. The absolute client ID is the full client ID (as you can see in the generated HTML output), prefixed with the naming container separator character (which defaults to `:`).

So, this should do

```
<f:ajax ... render=":contracts:contractIdInputText" />
```

*(assuming that the `<form id="contracts">` is by itself not in another `NamingContainer` parent, again, just check the generated HTML output to be sure)*

As to why you need to click the command link twice, this is most likely related to [JSF spec issue 790](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-790). A fix would be to explicitly include the other form in the `render`. See also [Ajax rendering of content which contains other form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm).